# I don't know how to wrap the .c file and.pyx file code

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I am beginner in Cython and I am learning it from a book of O’Reilly's Cython and I have an issue in  the code that I do not know that how I can wrap the code of .c file (C file) and .pyx file(Cython file) for making usable in python

the (wrap_fib.py file ) code is here:-

```
from distutils.core import setup,Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
ext=Extension(name='wrap_fib',sources=['wrap_fib_c.c','wrap_fib_cython.pyx'])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

the (wrap_fib_c.c file) code is here:-

```
double cfib(int n);
```

the (wrap_fib_cython.pyx file) code is here:-

```
cdef extern from "cfib.h":
double cfib(int n)
def fib(n):
return cfib(n)
```

if you want the code of 'fib.pyx' file so it is here:-

```
def fib(int n):
    cdef int i 
    cdef double a=0.0,b=1.0
    for i in range(n):
        a,b=a+b,a
    return a
```

i can't understand that from which of the command I will wrapped the code and make it useable. if I use the command `python wrap_fib.py build_ext --inplace`, so it will show the error such as:

```
wrap_fib_cython.c(699): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cfib.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

so can you please tell me that how i can solve this and what will I do for wrapped the code for python file. if you solve this I really appericate your efforts!! Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the problem is that you don't have a C header file. I'll leave a simple example for you to understand how it works.

Suppose that you have some random C function you want to use in a python program:

**c_code.c**

```
double add_c(double a, double b){
    return a + b;
}
```

To be able to use that function in other programs, you declare it inside a header file:

**c_code.h**

```
double add_c(double a, double b);
```

Then you need to write your cython code and import the function:

**cython_code.pyx**

```
# cython: language_level = 3

cdef extern from "c_code.h":

    cdef double add_c(double a, double b)

def add_cy(double a, double b):

    print(f"{a} + {b} = {add_c(a, b)}")
```

Now, you just need to write the setup script, compile the code, and the `add_c` function will be available for you to use in a python program.

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name="cython_code",
        sources=[
            "cython_code.pyx",
            "c_code.c"
        ]
    )
]

if __name__ == "__main__":

    setup(
        ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules)
    )
```

**foo.py**

```
from c_code import add_cy

add_cy(1., 3.)
```

## Using definition files

As you are reading the O'Reilly book, you will or may already have learned about the `.pxd` files, which are particularly suitable for this purpose. The implementation would look like this.

**cython_code.pxd**

```
cdef extern from "c_code.h":

    cdef double add_c(double a, double b)
```

**cython_code.pyx**

```
# cython: language_level = 3

def add_cy(double a, double b):

    print(f"{a} + {b} = {add_c(a, b)}")
```

As both the `.pyx` and the `.pxd` files have the same name, you don't even need to import the function, but the code would still work if you decide to add that extra line.